# Is it possible to block "external" requests from CSS?

Tags: css, security

I'm trying to develop a web application that would allow users to upload their own css to style the pages it serves, kind of like themes. These themes can be shared among users so I do not want anyone to be able to put references to "external" resources other than to my domain - so they can not harvest IP addresses or serve different content based on who makes the request and so on, it should be completely self-contained in the web app.

In another words, ONLY resources from specified domain should be available for retrieval and no other.

Is there any way to accomplish this or something with the same effect of preventing requests "external" of the web application?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a php script read the CSS file and find any references to files which use http://, https:// etc in their properties -  if they match it either strip it or warn the user to remove it.

Comment: This was the first thought I had but I'm not sure whether that is secure. Is "http" or "https" protocol **always** required for external requests? Isn't there any way potential attacker could craft that portion on-the-fly or using special characters?

These are hard questions to be sure of, that's why I'm looking for some "blanket" solution if it exists. I'd like to avoid parsing the CSS file ... only if there is NO OTHER solution would I attempt to do so.

Comment: I don't think the CSS will work properly, css it's not a scripting language with eval or exec functions or similar.For local stored images you would use relative paths or paths starting from the base url. Why is parsing the CSS an issue?

Comment: Although I suspect that leveraging abuses based on these would be difficult I'd recommend filtering all DATA urls, behaviour tags and also implementing a content security policy on the server.

Comment: It's a possible issue because I'm not completely sure I can catch all instances of external content being accessed. If I could get a confirmation that indeed only part of CSS that causes something to be requested is through "url" and all external links **must** start either with "http" or "https" there would be no problem but so far I'm not sure this is the case. Otherwise your solution would be ok, not ideal but ok :)

Comment: Even that I was aware of this possibility and was looking for some more, let's say elegant solution, I'll accept this answer as there doesn't appear to be any so far ...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply validate that all such URLs are indeed pointing to your domain.